# NIC dedicated to a KVM guest VM

Tags: networking, server, virtualization

I'm completly on a dead end trying to add a physical NIC to a guest VM.

The server has 4 NICs and I'd like to use as follow:
NIC1: host
NIC2: Dedicated to a windows VM
NIC3: dedicated to a pool of VM inside a bridge (at least 2)

The host is based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and using Cockpit to manage the VMs

I use KVM and qemu for virtualization

I've studied few sources but the fact that now there is netplan to manage the network mess up with old posts or at least does it for me. I have nothing against using netplan or other ways

Does anyone have latest wiki, howto, post to suggest from where to start fresh?

This is what I did:
in the VM I added a network interface,

```
- Direct
- source eno4 (nic)
- model (e1000e)
```

this is what is happening

```
- eno4 has an IP, let say 192.168.0.5 at the host side
- guest network (windows) as a different IP, let say 192.168.0.6
- in cockpit the network spec shows the IP of the default bridge
```

any clue?

thanks in advance